# Win7 throws "Cannot read /Boot/BCD" and even booting Windows 7 DVD fails with an error related to NTFS.SYS

Tags: windows-7, boot, ntfs, bcd

The last thing I did was a free-space wipe using iolo's tools, which errored out during the last 30%, throwing an error report toward iolo's support folks. Figuring it was something related to the fact I'd been running Win7 for almost a week without rebooting (using sleep mode), I shut down (which worked properly), waited 3 minutes and powered back up, only to get the error mentioned.

Now, my problem is that while I need to run CHKDSK /F /R against C:, I can't seem to get a boot disk that actually allows me to, which is weird stuff.

The MBR seems to be all right, since I dual-boot Win7 Home Premium x64 and Linux Mint 17.1 x64, and am writing this via Linux Mint 17.1, but understandably, I'd prefer to get this one solved without undue fuss.

Answer (score 0):

- Use MemTest to check your RAM
- Use your hard drive diagnostics or Ultimate Boot CD to check for bad sectors

Comment: Still looking for the correct HD tester for Toshiba-branded drives; have heard that the Fujitsu diagnostic is the proper one, but don't want (or need) to mess things up. Also trying to get SpinRite 6 to run on the machine in question, but FreeDOS apparently despises Toshiba laptops.